# Displaying .png files in java

Tags: java, png

I can display the text contained a .txt or .rtf file in java using this,

```
 import java.io.*;
 class test
 {
     public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
     {
         File f=new File("C:\\Users\\shinj\\Documents\\LIVE\\BEGINNER.txt");  
         String  path = f.getAbsolutePath();//Pass file's absolute path
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
         String line =null;
         for (int i =1;i<=14;i++)
         {
             line=reader.readLine();
             System.out.println(line);
         }
     }
 }
```

But the same doesn't happen for any .png files.

What I want to know is that is there any way to display the contents of a .png files in the terminal output screen of java.

For example, if there is a picture of a stickman in such a file, I want to display the stickman on the terminal window.

Comment: Is your terminal even *capable* of displaying images?  Terminals tend to be text-based things...

Comment: If you are looking for ASCII-Art conversion, check this example : https://gist.github.com/shmert/3859200

Answer (score 1):

Most of terminals can display only text data but some terminals allow to display emoji characters and images. For example [it is possible in iTerm for macOS](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-images.html).